# Вывод из файла txt

Tags: php

Есть файл file.txt с таким содержимым

```json
{"time":1580313148,"users":{"1580313196":"Sibroy"},"chats":[{"user":"Sibroy","date":"29 January 18:24","chat":"privet mir!!!"},{"user":"Sibroy","date":"29 January 18:51","chat":"privet strana"},{"user":"Sibroy","date":"29 January 18:52","chat":"\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442"}]}
```

как вывести что бы было

> Sibroy 29 january 18:52 privet strana.

и так три последних сообщения из этого файла

Comment: Вам нужно вывести содержимое массива `chats`?

Comment: Именно так...последние несколько сообщений из него

Comment: Каким образом в файл произошла запись ?

Comment: Это чат от сюда https://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/script-chat-simple_s2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в файле находится JSON объект. Соответственно, чтобы достать из него данные нужно сделать три вещи

1. Прочитать файл

   ```
   $str = file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
   if ($str === false)
     die('File read error');
   ```
2. Распарсить полученную строку

   ```
   $json = json_decode($str);
   if ($json === null)
     die('JSON parse error. ' . json_last_error_msg());
   ```
3. Вывести нужную информацию

   ```
   for ($i = max(0, count($json->chats) - 3); $i < count($json->chats); $i++) {
     $msg = $json->chats[$i];
     echo $msg->user;
     echo $msg->date;
     echo $msg->chat;
   }
   ```

Comment: Надо составить из этих кусков файл? так сделал выдаёт  HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: @user369873 Error 500 - ошибка сервера. Смотрите логи на сервере

Comment: [Thu Jan 30 06:47:24.154836 2020] [lsapi:notice] [pid 4007485] [client 213.87.127.121:34052] [host naceka-online.ru] Backend log: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant chats - assumed 'chats' in /var/www/u66268/data/www/naceka-online.ru/chat/lastchat.php on line 9\n
[Thu Jan 30 06:47:24.154852 2020] [lsapi:error] [pid 4007485] [client 213.87.127.121:34052] [host naceka-online.ru] Backend fatal error: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /var/www/u66268/data/www/naceka-online.ru/chat/lastchat.php on line 9\n ...это в третьем фрагменте кода

Comment: @user369873 Все отлично [работает](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a20c2b8e7d65cb610f1545642ed365b9c9a69ca). Проверьте еще раз свой код. У меня в исходном сообщении была ошибка, я для обращения к полям объектов вместо `->` использовал `.`

Comment: @user369873 `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` эта ошибка говорит о том, что вы считываете данный в другом формате, чем привели в вопросе. Что у вас оказалось на 9 строчке? Если это `echo $msg->user`, то значит, что в исходном файле поле `chats[].user` не строка, а какой-то объект. Для теста замените все `echo` на `var_dump($msg)` и покажите, что получилось

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает...

Comment: @user369873 ну тогда отметьте мой ответ как верный